# When to capitalize the abbreviation

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations

I'm writing a technical document about Linux and I wonder if I should type "tty driver" or "TTY driver" ? Which one, if any, is right and what is the general grammatic to follow in these cases?

My actual sentence with the expression is:

> The tty driver handles data that are sent between Linux’ tty and the modem card.

Comment: Looks like it's *generally* 'TTY', but there's a few cases of 'tty' (after a quick google)

Comment: Using upper case makes the plural easier, such as **TLAs**. With lower case there would be a temptation to use the ["greengrocer's apostrophe"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greengrocer%27s_apostrophe) such as with **tla's** to indicate that the **s** is not part of the abbreviation.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Strongly agree that the general term would be **TTY**. I suspect many **tty** mentions come from Unix-flavour operating systems where `/dev/tty` (and variants) are the file-like way of referring to a teletype, and where -- unlike Windows -- case in filenames matters. I would use upper case unless _specifically_ referring to the file-system entity.

Comment: @TripeHound I accept that as an answer if you write it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The normal case for TTY (as an abbreviation of "teletype" among others) would be all upper-case (see the [Teleprinter page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) for some confirmation and some history).

In fact, the use of all upper-case for such abbreviations (be they acronyms or -- as in this case -- initialisms) is very common<sup>**1**</sup> (see [Initialisms at Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/initialisms)). Plurals and possessives are then formed in the normal way ("*serveral TTYs in a row*" or "*the TTY's screen was broken*").

However, on Linux and other flavours of Unix, your current "teletype" (or however you connect) is mapped in the file-system to the (pseudo) file `/dev/tty`. Because *nix filenames are case-sensitive, if you are explicitly referring to "the tty device" (meaning the pseudo-file, and possibly the device-driver code behind it) using lower-case would be more common.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> I would have said all upper-case was near-universal (with the main exception being anything driven by marketing people looking to be "individual" or trendy). However, [this Language Log entry at UPenn](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005347.html) noted that there is (or was in 2008 when posted) a growing tendency in British newspapers to only use upper-case for the first letter. Not sure I've noticed this, but I try to avoid newspapers unless doing the crossword!